# How to render a form in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask and want to render a form. I came across a code for the same but am unable to render it as I don't know how and what to run

```
from collections import namedtuple
from wtforms import Form, FieldList, BooleanField, HiddenField, FormField
from webob.multidict import MultiDict

GroceryItem = namedtuple('GroceryItem', ['item_id', 'want', 'name'])

class GroceryItemForm(Form):
    item_id = HiddenField()
    want = BooleanField()

class GroceryListForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroceryListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # just a little trickery to get custom labels
        # on the list's checkboxes
        for item_form in self.items:
            for item in kwargs['data']['items']:
                if item.item_id == item_form.item_id.data:
                    item_form.want.label ='' 
                    item_form.label = item.name

    items = FieldList(FormField(GroceryItemForm))

item1 = GroceryItem(1, True, 'carrots')
item2 = GroceryItem(2, False, 'cornmeal')

data = {'items': [item1, item2]}

form = GroceryListForm(data=MultiDict(data))

print form.items()
```

I want a form to be rendered, wherein user selects an option and submits it to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask is an MVC and as such needs a Model, a View and a Controller. What you have created is only the model for the form and some controller code to create a grocery list. However simply printing form items will not render anything. You need to create a view that will render the form using Jinja2 or any other templating language

Since you are using FlaskWTForms, you can check out its documentation here:
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

You can also look into this excellent tutorial by Miguel Grinberg if you are new to Flask:
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms

Comment: Another good source of information is the flask official documents at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/. If you closely follow the post there you might get to creating of a form with WTF forms. As @TheGeorgeous said you should also take a look at the templating system in flask which is by default Jinja2 http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/